# DOS command in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, execution

I want to ask about a command in Python that performs exactly like the `dos()` command in MATLAB. For instance, I have the following code block in MATLAB and I want to do exactly the same in Python.

```
**DIANA = '"C:\Program Files\Diana 10.3\\bin\\DianaIE.exe"'; 
MODEL = 'Input.dcp'; 
INPUTDIR = 'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Thesis\PSO\'; 
OUTPUTDIR = 'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Thesis\PSO\'; 
OUTPUT = 'FILE_OUTPUT.out'; 
WORKDIRINPUT = sprintf('%s%s',INPUTDIR,MODEL);
WORKDIROUTPUT = sprintf('%s%s',OUTPUTDIR,OUTPUT);
%
NAMES = sprintf('%s  %s  %s',DIANA,WORKDIRINPUT,WORKDIROUTPUT);
disp('Start DIANA');
dos(NAMES);
disp('End DIANA');**
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute a block of code and get the output in python inside the code you can use a function called exec() and pass the expression or the code to be executed as a string.

This accepts the code as a string. Example..

```
code = 'x=100\nprint(x)'
exec(code)
```

Output:

```
100
```

And if you want to use the command prompt or power shell commands in python you should you a library named os in python

```
import os
os.system('cd document')
```

you can use os.path module for manipulation path and a lot more to know more about this go through this documentation [OS-Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

Comment: In python mostly you'll run the code in command prompt, terminal, or the PowerShell so I think this will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
```

> subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\Diana 10.3\bin\DianaIE.exe',
> 'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Thesis\PSO\Input.py'])